# Symfony 4 / Webpack Encore - Recover and apply CSS style dynamically from the database

Tags: database, symfony4, webpack-encore

I am currently developing a Symfony 4 application for a client.
I obviously use Webpack Encore for asset management.
But I find myself exposed to a problem.
For the needs of the client it should be possible to override the global variables (color, rounding, etc.) of my default style by those defined in the admin interface.
And that's where I'm stuck. No worries to save in bdd the style defined by the client (json format) but to recover them and apply them to the application (build of assets + overload); I have no idea how to do it ...

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

You will need to generate a css or sass file from the data in the database and then webpack encore will be able to manage it. You should trigger the update function on edit page save.

The database would then just be used to display the current status on the edit page, and css would effect the page.